# create separate search form for separate fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a search form which is hidden (drop down when click on) and it worked good, but I need to create multiple forms, to send post request to php with different fields.

This is html code and script:

```js
$(function() {
 var $searchlink = $('#searchtoggl i');
 var $searchbar = $('#searchbar');

 $('#topnav ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).attr('id') == 'searchtoggl') {
   if (!$searchbar.is(":visible")) {
    // if invisible we switch the icon to appear collapsable
    $searchlink.removeClass('fa-search').addClass('fa-search-minus');
   } else {
    // if visible we switch the icon to appear as a toggle
    $searchlink.removeClass('fa-search-minus').addClass('fa-search');
   }

   $searchbar.slideToggle(300, function() {
    // callback after search bar animation
   });
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<div id="w">
  <header id="topbar" class="clearfix">
    <div id="logo">Dynatable</div>

    <nav id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="searchtoggl"><i class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="searchbar" class="clearfix">
    <form id="searchform" method="post" action="searchpage.php">
      <tr>
        <td>orgid:</td>
        <textarea id="textarea" name="orgId"></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Org Name:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="textarea" type="text" name="orgName" /></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Primary Domain:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="textarea" type="text" name="primaryDomain" /></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Partner Name:</td>
        <td>
          <textarea id="textarea" type="text" name="PartnerName" /></textarea>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <br>
        <br>
        <td>
          <input id=searchsubmit type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </div>
```

It is functional and I can add multiple fields in same form, but as per my requirement I need to create separate search field to send request to php.

How can achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><select id="select" name="select">
        <option>orgid</option>
        <option>orgName</option>
        <option>PrimaryDomain</option>
        <option>PartnerName</option>
       </select></td><br>
    <textarea id="textarea" name="key" style="margin: 0px 0px 10px; width: 600px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

and you get what you wanted